# Is possible with a Regex extract the body of "IF" statement in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I need a Regex that extract in PHP with the method "preg_match_all" all match found in a java source code about if statement. I have found one that match a if declaration, but I also need to capture the contents of the block. If you have any suggestions to improve my regex or simply have a better one then please submit an answer.

Here is my regex: `/(?:if|else).*\{/`

this is the result:

```
array(1
0   =>  array(3
0   =>  if(i=1){
1   =>  if(i=2){
2   =>  else{
)
)
```

What i'm looking for is something like that:

```
array(1
0   =>  array(3
0   =>  if(i=1){
0   =>  c++;
0   =>  }
1   =>  if(i=2){
1   =>  c=c+2;
1   =>  }
2   =>  else{
2   =>  c--;
2   =>  }
)
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks! In other words: when you have php code that doesnt work - show that code here!

Answer (score 1):

Structure of a regular **if/else** statement is following

```
if (<condition>) 
{ <body> }
else [if (<condition>)]
{ <body> }
```

Everywhere in between keywords whitespaces may be encountered. Therefore, you should take that into account.

Here is an example of regex that would locate simple if/else statement. It would not be able to find **else if** block.

```
if\([\w\s!=|&^]*\)\s*{[^}]*}(\s*else(\s*if\([\w\s!=|&^]*\))*\s*{[^}]*})*
```

This regex isn't the perfect solution for sure and it will also require adaptation for the engine use use. You can check how it works [here](http://regexr.com/3gh7r).

Comment: I'm not a Regex pro, but due to the many different formatting styles of `if` statements, would it not be better to replace `{.+}` with `{[\s\S]+}` so that you can match the `{` being on the same line as the `(<condition>)`.

Comment: `{.+}` and `{[\s\S]+}` do nothing with condition-to-statement body area. They match all the characters inside the curly braces.

Comment: Aye so if the statement is `if (<condition>) { LINEBREAK` your original Regex wouldn't pick it up? It is a very common style in quite a few languages to have the opening curly brace on the same line as the condition. i.e. http://regexr.com/3gh70

Comment: @Pigeon It would depend on regex engine a lot and parameters passed to it. **multiline** option or explicit `\n` character should be taken into consideration as well as format of the string upon which regex is used.

Comment: @hrust Sorry I tried but your suggestion does not work, I'm using this site to test http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: @Stefano I have updated regex and added an example on how it works (see the link). You will probably need to adapt it for the php regex engine with all the flags and options that suite your particular case.

Comment: @hrust Ok, i saw, but with php preg_match_all it doesn't work, furthermore I saw if I change the construct with "else if (<condition>)" does not find any match, also the example below

`private function x (){
 if(true){
  if(!true){ c++;}
  i++;
 }else{
  i--;
 }
}`

Comment: @Stefano I am not from PHP world and I cannot say how regex engine in it, as well as regex that I provided does not see nested if/else blocks. However, I've updated my answer so that regex now detects multiple blocks of **else if**.